# Why is visual studio committing files in my .gitignore file?

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013, gitignore

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 Express using Git on a project.

I created my repository and copied the project files into it from another directory.  I then checked my `.gitignore` and `.gitattributes` files.  `.gitignore` was pre-configured and looked to cover everything I needed to ignore for commits at this point.

I selected the Changes tab in Visual Studio under the "Team Explorer" tab and saw all my files were untracked, as expected.  I then clicked "Add All".  I assumed VS would only add files not matching those in my `.gitignore` to the "Included Changes" list.  Instead, all the files were added to the "Included Changes" list.

I then thought that maybe the `.gitignore` file would be used when committing and that only files not matching those in `.gitignore` would be committed.  So I added a commit message and clicked "Commit".

When I select "View History" from the "Actions" drop down in the "Changes" tab I am presented with a pane to the left of my "Team Explorer" view that shows all the commits I've made.  There is only 1 commit.  When I double click that commit, the "Team Explorer" tab displays `Commit 8db34b1c` and all the files in my project are listed there in the tree view with [add] after their name.

For example, `App_Data/Movies.mdf` and `App_Data/Movies.ldf` are listed even though my `.gitignore` includes the lines

```
# SQL Server files
App_Data/*.mdf
App_Data/*.ldf
```

I don't understand how the .gitignore file is being used here or what the "Included Changes", "Excluded Changes" or "Untracked Files" sections mean.

An explanation of the above behavior and sections would be appreciated.

Edit--

I deleted my .git directory, created a new repo, copied my project files in again and then took screenshots of what I see.

Here are images of my .gitignore file and my "Changes" tab.

[image] [image]

There's [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18618760/tfs-git-extensions-seems-to-ignore-gitignore) and [this msdn question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18618760/tfs-git-extensions-seems-to-ignore-gitignore) which shows that other people seem to be having issues as well.  I tried deleting the .xml file added by VS in my .git directory (as noted in the msdn question) but that did not solve the issue for me.

Edit 2 --

This is my current directory structure :

```
/MvcMovie/
    |--.git/
    |
    |---MvcMovie/
    |       |--App_Data/
    |       |     |--Movies.mdf
    |       |     |--Movies.ldf
    |       |     
    |       |--App_Start/
    |       |--etc...
    |
    |--packages/
    |--.gitignore
    |--.gitattributes
    |--MvcMovie.sln
    |MvcMovie.v12.suo
```

Comment: Is your git repo (indicated by the `.git` file) in the MvcMovie directory or above MvcMovie directory?

Comment: My git repo is in the top MvcMovie directory.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

@dustinmoris is right in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28637437/316857), but the fix is not as immediately obvious as the procedure would lead you to believe.  So let me explicitly walk you through the process to make sure the files in your `.gitignore` file are obeyed by Visual Studio.

**1. Create Your Solution & Add It To Source Control**
[image: Visual Studio 2013 Solution Creation]

I created a sample [MVVM Light](http://www.mvvmlight.net/) XAML Solution and you can see that all the currently untracked files that should ideally be added to the next commit show up with a little green plus next to their icons.

[image: Solution directory listing]

The problem is that the `MvvmLight.Win81_TemporaryKey.pfx` file is listed to be added even though all files of type `.pfx` are explicitly called out to be ignored in my `.gitignore`.

[image: gitignore]

This is even more obvious if I select the solution in the `Team Explorer` panel and then select the `Changes` button.  I see a list of all files pending inclusion on the next commit.

[image: Team Explorer Changes]

This list contains every file in the Solution, not just the subset specified by the `.gitignore` file.

**2. Close Visual Studio & Delete the `ms-persist.xml` File**

It's in a hidden directory so it's kind of hard to find.  It should be located at the following path

> *Solution Directory*\.git\ms-persist.xml

[image: ms-persist.xml file]

**3. Re-Open The Solution and Commit Files**

You'll notice that it appears as if your solution is no longer under source control because all the icons have lost their green plus signs, but don't worry it's fine.

[image: Solution directory listing after deleting ms-persist.xml]

Head on over to the `Team Explorer` panel and then select the `Changes` button.  Again, you'll see that the project is still being tracked by source control, as well as a list of all files to be added on the next commit.  More importantly, you'll notice that your `.gitignore` list was properly adhered to this time and all files specified as ignored are no longer listed as pending changes to be added to the next commit.  As you can see below, the `MvvmLight.Win81_TemporaryKey.pfx` file is no longer scheduled for the next commit!

[image: Corrected commit changes]

Hope that helps someone. After all that hassle here is my honest advice:

> Learn and use the command line interface since it provides the full
>   range of functionality git offers and has the same interface on all
>   platforms.

Comment: TLDR Version, delete `.git\ms-persist.xml` and restart Visual Studio. Thanks, that helped.

Comment: Nice answer; especially the final sentence. I have come to the same conclusion after battling with too many so-called UIs with their endless quirks.

Comment: Have seen this myself where applying the mentioned fix did not stick - files got re-added after doing a clean rebuild. Looking at .gitignore I found it to have **UNIX EOL**. Switching to **Windows EOL** did the trick.

Answer (score 4):

If anyone ever wonders how to fix it. This is the solution:
Go to your .git folder (might be hidden) and open up the ms-persist.xml and you can see the tracked files, excluded items, etc.

Just manually fix what VS has messed up and restart the IDE and you should be good again!

Don't delete the whole .git folder like it is often mentioned on other SO threads!

Thanks to Eric Nelson's blog post:
https://ericnelson.wordpress.com/2014/06/21/is-visual-studio-2013-ignoring-your-gitignore-file/

Answer (score 2):

`AppData/*.mdf` and `AppData/*.ldf` refer to `.mdf` and `.ldf` files that exist in the `AppData` directory that is in the root of your git repository.

Your `AppData` directory actually exists beneath the `MvcMovie` directory.  You can add:

```
MvcMovie/AppData/*.mdf
MvcMovie/AppData/*.ldf`
```

to your `.gitignore` to ignore those specific files, or, if you want to ignore the `.mdf` and `.ldf` directories in *all* `AppData` folders throughout your repository:

```
**/AppData/*.mdf
**/Appdata/*.ldf
```

Comment: Given how Visual Studio sets up the .gitignore file, how should I be creating my repos and/or projects so that I don't have to adjust the .gitignore with each new project.

For example there is a line !packages/*/build/ which seems to target my packages folder but that is at the same directory level as the project folder and the .gitignore file, which means (if I'm reading this correctly) the App_Data/*.mdf line would not apply as it is currently.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the SQL database file specifications in the .gitignore to:

```
# SQL Server files
*.mdf
*.ldf
```

Wouldn't that ignore all SQL database files throughout the entire solution folder tree, no matter what subfolder it was found in?

Answer (score 0):

1. In **Team Explorer**, go to your solution and then to the changes view.
2. Select the silly files you want to exclude.
3. Right click and select **Ignore this extension**.
   [image: Team Explorer - Ignore this extension]
4. You will see that there have been changes made to the .gitignore which you can now commit.

## .gitignore

```
*.ldf
*.mdf
```

Or you can use the Ignore this local item to only ignore that specific item if you don't want to ignore an extension completely.