# gitignore not ignoring *some* files

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013

I have a file structure similar to this in my project:

```
-project root
  .gitignore
  -Scripts (folder)
    fileA.js
    fileB.js
    -maps (folder)
      fileA.js.map
      fileB.js.map
```

And a .gitignore file that contains:

```
**/*.map
Scripts/**
```

(among other entries)

However, when I use Visual Studio 2013 to stage a commit (right-click on solution and select Commit) I still see fileA.js.map, fileB.js.map and fileA.js (but NOT fileB.js) in the "Included Changes" section.

This is a brand new repo, with no commits so Git is not aware of any of these files. These files are generated by Gulp which is why I do not want them in my repo.

I've tried so many different permutations in .gitignore that I can't remember them all.  Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Where the files part of repository before? In that case you need to reset them, and after that they will be ignored by git

Comment: Is your goal to ignore the maps folder, or ignore all .map files in your project? Also, the line `Scripts/**` looks like it's attempting to ignore the entire Scripts folder, but that's not what you wanted, right?

Comment: @Roman: no these are all new files.

Comment: @Maximillian: This sample is just an excerpt of my full project, but yes, I'm  trying to ignore all map files in Scripts\maps as well as ignore all .js files in Scripts

Comment: @David Do you want to ignore the entire Scripts folder and everything in it, or only the *.js files in it? Ignore the entire maps folder and everything in it, or only the *.map files in it?

Comment: Ignore .js files in Scripts and everything in Scripts\maps

Comment: So it appears that the VS2013 Team Explorer is showing ignored files.  When I open the project using Git Extensions (version 2.47.3) the files to be committed are correct.  When I opt in the Commit dialog Git Extensions to show Ignored Files, the errant files show up.  I can't find any way to configure Team Explorer, so I'm assuming this is a bug?  Seems pretty major to have been around this long, unless it's "as-designed" and I'm just approaching it wrong.  It's weird that only some ignored files show up, though...

Comment: this may help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/28807810/202

Comment: @ChristianHagelid: Yep, that did the trick!  Thanks.